# What is the hybridisation of carbon in transition state in SN2 mechanism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hybridization, nucleophilic-substitution

Normally, a carbon atom is $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridized, whereas in a transition state five bonds are present, then what's the hybridisation of carbon?

Comment: http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/vlu_organik/substitution/sn_2/sn_2.vlu/Page/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/substitution/sn_2/uebergangszustand/uebergangszustand_sn2.vscml.html

Comment: Related: [How are SN2 transition states stabilised by adjacent double bonds and carbonyl groups?](//chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/48872)

Answer (score 5):

In transition state of S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism, the carbon atom is $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridised due to its planar structure. At this point, carbon almost acquires 'pentavalency' with three full bonds and two 'partial' bonds, and a planar complex is formed, which is $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridised.